# how to compare a Double Value in if statement in java?

Tags: java

I have a desktop application with textboxs that contain a price values. As an example if i input 25000

```
Double priceSec = Double.parseDouble(cusPrice.getText());
```

i'm passing that 25000 as a double value

so now i want to compare that value and check whether it is empty or not?

```
if(cusPrice2.getText()==null || cusPrice2.getText().isEmpty()){
        Double priceSec=0.0;
        }
```

i know i can create an else condition for

```
if textbox !=null
total=txtbox1+txtbox2+txtbox3;
```

if textbox value is empty or not empty. value should be there in total.
but  in my code ,it displays as null.

Do i have any other way to do that?
can you tell me a way to do that.

here is my full code

```
  private void cusOkBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    Double priceSec = Double.parseDouble(cusPrice2.getText());
    Double priceThird = Double.parseDouble(cusPrice3.getText());
    Double priceFourth = Double.parseDouble(cusPrice4.getText());
    Double priceFifth = Double.parseDouble(cusPrice5.getText());

    if(cusPrice2.getText()==null || cusPrice2.getText().isEmpty() || cusPrice2.getText() !=null ){
            priceSec=0.0;
            costCls.setItemPrice(priceSec);
            }
            else if(cusPrice3.getText()==null || cusPrice3.getText().isEmpty()){
            priceThird=0.0;
            }
            else if(cusPrice4.getText()==null || cusPrice4.getText().isEmpty()){
            priceFourth=0.0;
            }
            else if(cusPrice5.getText()==null || cusPrice5.getText().isEmpty()){
            priceFifth=0.0;
            }

           Double setItemTotal = priceCus+priceSec+priceThird+priceFourth+priceFifth;

}
```

Comment: You should check textbox value is empty or not before parsing it to double, and the double price variable you should initialize to 0. Please share complete code.

Comment: You should respond to the answers

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use `Exception`s.

```
try {
    Double priceSec = Double.parseDouble(cusPrice.getText());
} catch (NullPointerException e1) {
    //null somewhere
} catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
    //not a number - on controlled input - empty field.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the built-in `Exception` semantics already available within the `Double.parseDouble(String s)` implementation. (IMHO: Don't check up-front as you are making the exceptional-situation  part of the normal flow)

Use a function like

```
private static double getValue(String str) {
    try {
        return  Double.parseDouble(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return 0d;
    }
}
```

You would then use it like:

```
String priceStr = cusPrice.getText();
double d = getValue(priceStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`double` is the primitive type for floating point, `Double` is the Object child that wraps a double value. So:

```
double priceSec = Double.parseDouble(cusPrice.getText());

double price2Sec = cusPrice2.getText().isEmpty())
        ? 0.0
        : Double.parseDouble(cusPrice.getText());

if (priceSec == price2Sec) { ...
```

However for financial data a double has small approximation errors, that can become visible - especially with `==`. Hence one might better use BigDecimal, which does fixed point arithmetic.

```
 BigDecimal priceSec = new BigDecimal(cusPrice.getText());
 if (priceSec.compareTo(price2Sec) == 0) { ...
```

With a bit ugly API doing calculations:

```
 x = x.add(y.divide(new BigDecimal("12.50")));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
private void cusOkBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    Double priceSec=0.0,priceThird=0.0,priceFourth=0.0,priceFifth=0.0;
    costCls.setItemPrice(0.0);


    if(cusPrice2.getText()!=null && !cusPrice2.getText().isEmpty() ){
        priceSec = Double.parseDouble(cusPrice2.getText());
        costCls.setItemPrice(priceSec);
    }
    else if(cusPrice3.getText()!=null && !cusPrice3.getText().isEmpty()){
        priceThird = Double.parseDouble(cusPrice3.getText());
    }
    else if(cusPrice4.getText()!=null && !cusPrice4.getText().isEmpty()){
        priceFourth = Double.parseDouble(cusPrice4.getText());
    }
    else if(cusPrice5.getText()!=null && !cusPrice5.getText().isEmpty()){
        priceFifth = Double.parseDouble(cusPrice5.getText());
    }

   Double setItemTotal = priceCus+priceSec+priceThird+priceFourth+priceFifth;

}
```